# Simple Chrome extension w/ Context Menu cmds that call VB .net procedures

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, contextmenu

I'm looking for some input on how feasible it would be to create a Chrome extension that, when activated via toolbar button, adds context menu commands that call procedures (or methods of a class) written in VB.net.

That's pretty much it. At this point, i'd be thrilled to see context menu items that simply display message boxes built in VB.net.

I'm starting with Chrome, but would anticipate replicating similar functionality in other browsers, starting with Edge or IE, then Firefox and possibly Safari. If it's easier to start with another widely used browser besides Chrome, i'd be fine with that.

I've done the obvious google searches, and I can't seem to find an easy-ish place to start. Any ideas?

--edit, just an additional note, the VB.net procedures would be contained in a dll, exe, or other container installed on the client side machine. I'm not trying to execute server side code

Comment: **This is me just guessing and explaining the things I know and have read:** To build chrome extensions, you need to know the programming languages such as HTML, CSS, Javascript. [SOURCE](https://www.quora.com/In-what-programming-language-are-Chrome-extensions-written-What-do-I-need-to-know-to-start-coding-them). I always say that everything is possible especially with coding, but it depends on how much time and effort you want to put into it. There is probably someway you can create a chrome extension with VB.NET but it would require more knowledge that I have.

Comment: I found this link containing information how you can build a chrome extension. It is for C# though. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185723/Develop-Your-First-Google-Chrome-Extension-Using-H